# How to use SUPER class while extending it from an Abstract class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an abstract class which has 4 arguments in its own constructor:

```
export abstract class AbstractType implements OnInit, Destroy{
constructor(
      protected readonly abc: abc,
      protected readonly def: def,
      protected readonly ghi: ghi,
      protected readonly jkl: jkl) {}

}
```

I am adding a subclass which extends the above abstract class and also have two new arguments in this subclass:

```
export abstract class SubAbstractType extends AbstractType{
    constructor(
          protected readonly mno: mno,
          protected readonly pqr: pqr) {}
    super(mno, pqr);
    }
```

I have an error here on Super Class which says

> expected 4 arguments, but got 2

can someone help me solve this and explain it please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your AbstactType needs 4 parameters so you need to call super with those 4 parameters

```
export abstract class SubAbstractType extends AbstractType{
    constructor(
          abc: abc,
          def: def,
          ghi: ghi,
          jkl: jkl
          protected readonly mno: mno,
          protected readonly pqr: pqr) {}
    super(abc, def, ghi, jkl);
    }
```